# What controls are they using and how?

Tags: ios

So I'm creating a new app for a friend of mine, and I was looking around and came across this app.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alvarado-isd/id442436936?mt=8

I was wondering, what type of controls are the "buttons" like the "News" and "Staff" buttons, and how do they add them?

I know it's a tabbed application, and I thought they were using a TableView and maybe a Button with an icon, but I can't figure out how they would use a TableView.

Sorry for the most likely obvious question, and thanks for the help as always.

Comment: Looks like three20 to me. This question would be improved by including a screenshot, not everyone can or will follow app store links, and it's in less danger of being assumed spam then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that they are just a standard UIButton, you can set the type to Custom and then select the Image you want to show as the button face.

Answer (score 1):

They look like buttons to me. They could have put the whole app together in interface builder pretty quickly.

If you click the 'i' on the resources page you will se the company that made the app; you could contact them for more information if you like.